# How to store response from async call into global variable for further processing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am stuck since 1 week and can't get this working properly. Yes i am new to everything on front-end so please bare with me -

I am trying to store the response from subscribe to global variable for further processing -

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.http.get<APIResponse>('url' + globals.applicationId, { headers: httpHeaders })
      .pipe(map((res: APIResponse) => res))
      .subscribe(res => {

        //setting apiresponse for global usage
        this.apiresponse = res;

        console.log(this.apiresponse); //prints what i want

      });

      console.log(this.apiresponse); //prints undefined
}
```

I understand that for SO community this is probably the question that has been asked trillion times but i saw many post with different use cases and not a single response i could find with proper implementation hence i am here seeking help. I would appreciate if someone can help me without marking this question closed or duplicate. Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm guessing `this.http.get` is asynchronous so checking the value of `this.apiresponse` right after calling `this.http.get` will not show you the defined value. If you check later (you can use `setTimeout(() => console.log(this.apiresponse), 2000)` to test), is `this.apiresponse` defined?

Comment: @HenryWoody interesting with that i am getting the response. Do you recommend i settimeout and then store the response into global variable ?

Comment: You don't need to use setTimeout, that's just for testing here, and you already have code that does that (in `subscribe`). This is async code so it will run at the same time that other parts of your code run. You need to write the rest of your code to handle that `this.apiresponse` will not be defined until `this.http.get` has finished. With Angular you would do this by showing a loading state and then updating when the request finishes.

Comment: okay that was super helpful just needed someone to tap on my head thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Your `console.log` that prints `undefined` is run before the one inside the `subscribe` block. This is due to the asynchronous nature of the call to get.

In short, it work's as designed.

Answer (score 0):

The API Response Data in the global variable `this.apiresponse` is stored as you want it to be.

The issue is how you are verifying this behavior.

You need to be aware of how JS code executes, how `async call` works, and most importantly when `callbacks` are executed.

In this case:

The Subscription callback function executes when the GET API call is complete (Response is returned from the Backend Server) and as Javascript does not wait for this call to get complete, the Javascript engine continues to execute the code outside the `subscription()` and when API call is successful, it triggers subscription callback function and executes that. So, The first `console.log()` (Inside subscription block) in your case is executed after the `console.log()` outside subscription block
This is why `console.log()` inside the subscription block prints the correct value but `console.log()` outside the subscription block does not as at the time it was executed API was not complete hence data was not present.

You can call a function inside the subscription block to work on the data. Hope this helps!

Comment: this is exactly what i did i.e. call function inside subscription block but one take away was that everytime this function is invoked it will trigger rest call which i was trying to avoid hence i wanted to save this into global variable for further usage